# block until ExecutorService is done

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blocking, executorservice

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [ExecutorService, how to wait for all tasks to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish)
>   [Java ExecutorService: awaitTermination of all recursively created tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958330/java-executorservice-awaittermination-of-all-recursively-created-tasks)

Is there a way to block the current thread until an `ExecutorService` has finished all its tasks?

```
executor.execute(task1);
executor.execute(task2);
executor.execute(task3);
executor.execute(task4);
executor.execute(task5);
// ...now I want to block until all tasks have finished executing...
System.out.println("done!")
```

Comment: use `invokeAll`, and then call `get` on the returned `Future` objects...it's analogous to `Thread.join()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) with a pool size set to [`System.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29)<sup>Java 6</sup> or [`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29)<sup>Java 8</sup> and `.execute()` it all the tasks you want to execute, then call `tpe.shutdown()` and then wait in a `while(!tpe.terminated()) { /* waiting for all tasks to complete */}` which blocks for all the submitted tasks to complete. *where `tpe` is a reference to your `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance.*

Or if it is more appropriate use an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) A [CompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) that uses a supplied Executor to execute tasks. This class arranges that submitted tasks are, upon completion, placed on a queue accessible using take. The class is lightweight enough to be suitable for transient use when processing groups of tasks.

Comment: `while(!tpe.terminated()) {}` is busy-waiting.

Answer (score 7):

For all your tasks, put them into a List callables then invokeAll on them

```
ExecutorService e = ...

e.invokeAll(callables);
```

Per javadocs

> Executes the given tasks, returning a
>   list of Futures holding their status
>   and results when all complete.
>   Future.isDone() is true for each
>   element of the returned list. Note
>   that a completed task could have
>   terminated either normally or by
>   throwing an exception. The results of
>   this method are undefined if the given
>   collection is modified while this
>   operation is in progress.

Thus the thread will wait until all tasks haven been completed